# Why is there an error "no suitable constructor found" for my String[]?

Tags: java

The error is that there is no "suitable constructor found" for TestPayroll with this statement:
`Payroll payroll = new Payroll(name, weeksPay);`

What should the constructor be? I assume it should be in the Payroll class.

I want to display the pay for the week for Tiny Tim, Brad Pitt, and Madonna.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestPayroll {

    private String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
    private double [] payRate = {100.25, 150.50, 124.25};
    private double [] hrsWorked = {40, 35, 36};
    private double weeksPay;
    
    //Payroll object
    Payroll payroll = new Payroll(name, weeksPay);
        
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    
    //Display weekly pay
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "%s's pay for the week is: $%.2f\n", payroll[0].getName(), payroll[0].getWeeksPay()); 
        
    }   
                    
}

public class Payroll {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        }
        
        private String name;
        private double payRate;
        private double hrsWorked;
        private double weeksPay;
        
        //default constructor
        public Payroll() {
            this.name = name;
            this.payRate = payRate;
            this.hrsWorked = hrsWorked;
            this.weeksPay = weeksPay;
        }
        
        //Payroll constructor
        public Payroll(String name, double weeksPay) {
            this.name = name;
            this.weeksPay = weeksPay;
        }
                
        //return name
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
        //set name
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        //return pay rate
        public double getPayRate() {
            return payRate;
        }
        
        //set pay rate
        public void setPayRate(double payRate) {
            this.payRate = payRate;
        }
        
        //return hours worked for the week
        public double getHrsWorked() {
            return hrsWorked;
        }
        
        //set hours worked for the week
        public void setHrsWorked(double hrsWorked) {
            this.hrsWorked = hrsWorked;
        }
        
        //find week's pay
        public double getWeeksPay(double weeksPay) {
            double weeksPay = payRate * hrsWorked;
            return weeksPay;
        }   
                    
}
```

Comment: You are passing `String[]` and your constructor takes `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have following constructors for `Payroll`

```
    public Payroll(String name, double weeksPay) {/* some code */}
```

and

```
    public Payroll() {/* some */}
```

and you are passing `String[]` as first argument

Comment: How am I passing String[] as first arg?

Comment: @Grafica in `TestPayroll` class, `name` variable is `String[] name`.

Comment: So what is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Grafica a single instance of `String`, for example `name[0]` for `Tiny Tim`

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: what line are you referring to that name[0] should be in?

Comment: `Payroll payroll = new Payroll(name, weeksPay);`

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: Like this? 'Payroll payroll = new Payroll(name[], weeksPay);'
What should my JOptionPane statement look like, since I want to display the week's pay associated with ea. name?

Comment: The code is supposed to have private data members for an employee's name, hourly rate pay, number of hours worked, and total pay for the week. The array of 3 Payroll objects is instantiated manually with the number of hours each employee worked.  I want to display the week's pay for each employee.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33379/discussion-between-grafica-and-jigar-joshi)

Answer (score 1):

```
   //Payroll constructor. your argument types is String and double.
    public Payroll(String name, double weeksPay) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weeksPay = weeksPay;
    }
```

But

```
  //Payroll object
  Payroll payroll = new Payroll(name, weeksPay); // you are using String[] array and double as in put arguments.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you are calling, which takes an argument as a single string:

```
//Payroll constructor
        public Payroll(String name, double weeksPay)
```

And here are the calls you are making:

```
    //Payroll object
    Payroll payroll = new Payroll(name, weeksPay);
```

Where the objects are referenced name as a string array object rather than passing a single string:

```
    private String [] name = {"Tiny Tim", "Brad Pitt", "Madonna"};
```

Try it with an enumerator to pass the value one by one.
OR
You can create a constructor for string array where the same logic needs to be added into a constructor rather than the main method.